# How to print all the request headers which HttpURLConnection is sending?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I am using HttpURLConnection in one of my Java program to hit a HTTP URL via Java.

I know I can set the request header value something like this.

connObj.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "curl/7.29");

But I want to print all the request headers which is generated by URLConnection. Is that possible?

Comment: Maybe [getRequestProperties()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getRequestProperties()) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

How about calling `getRequestProperties()` which as the documentation states

> Returns an unmodifiable Map of general request properties for this connection.